# How to begin working with RFID Reader?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, rfid

I want to write  the program that manages the parking (Smart Parking).

I have just bought a RFID Reader, but I don't know how to begin with it.

Someone can tell me how to programming by using C++/C# to interact with this RFID Reader.

Many Thanks,

T&T

Comment: Does this RFID reader has a API? How are you planning to use this reader? More detail will be nice. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: @sam: I have just searched on internet, but I don't sure that which one that I really need, I want to use RFID Reader to build the "Smart Parking" application, can you show me where I should begin. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is no "RfidReader" class in .NET or C++, at least not one in the standard libraries. Each reader is propritary and has it's own way of interfacing.

I would start by reading the documentaion for the reader you bought. If you tell us the make and model of it we can point you in the right direction and potentially find the correct documentation..

Comment: Its model is CR10MW, Reader Type is "Mifare", please help me, thank you!